# Attempting to write a COUNT(*) Query

Tags: mysql

Write a query that returns the names of the top five customers who have purchased the most songs from ATunes, ordered by the number of purchases (descending). I must also limit the results to the top 5 as stated.

```
SELECT P.CustomerID, A.FirstName, A.LastName, P.DateOfPurchase, COUNT(DateOfPurchase) as NumberOfPurchases
ORDER BY NumberOfPurchases DESC, LIMIT 0,5
FROM Purchases as P
JOIN ATunesCostumers as A on (A.CustomerID = P.CustomerID)
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

this is what I am trying, and I am getting a syntax error.
When I get rid of the ORDER BY and LIMIT statements I get everything I need for this, other than the limitation and correct ordering. I'm at a loss, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: order by should be the last clause right?

Comment: order by and limit should come at last not with columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.CustomerID, A.FirstName, A.LastName, P.DateOfPurchase, COUNT(DateOfPurchase) as NumberOfPurchases
FROM Purchases as P
JOIN ATunesCostumers as A on P.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY NumberOfPurchases DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0,5' at line 5

It's giving me the same error. I'm extremely greatful for the help though. I did attempt all that with out the LIMIT statement and it worked. So I'm going to try to plug in LIMIT somewhere else.

Comment: remove the comma please after DESC;